# Async get() w/o intermediary accumulator?

Tags: python, asynchronous, ray

I have the following loop. I simplified the code. inner() parses the same file in a similar loop, ofcourse w/o the .remote() call

```
def outer(self,file):
       rv = []
       with open(file,'r') as f :
            acc1, acc2 = [],[]
            for i,line in  enumerate(f) :
                 if i % 10 == 0 : print(f'> {i}  ', end="\n")
                 if i > 25 : break
                 outeri,txt = line.split(':')
                 abc = ClassX.inner.remote(txt, file, int(outeri))
                 acc2.append(abc) #lst of obj-refs
                 acc1.append(int(outeri)) 

            rv = [z for z in zip(acc1, ray.get([a for a in acc2])) ]
       return rv
```

I want to collect the data asynchronously into rv, which i do here, but w/o intermediary 'acc2'.

There are two problems I have :

1. Instead/In-addition-to collecting the data I want to asynchronously execute some SQL code, but as the results come in.
2. the print() progress is not printed progressively, but at once at the end. I have to move it into "inner()"

Trying to understand Parallel iterators, but it seem hard/unfesable how can I squeeze the steps after readline upto the .remote() call

Answer (score 1):

Edit: changing answer in light of clarifications.

In order to process object refs in the order that they arrive, you'll want to use `ray.wait` to get the object refs as they return, then only call `ray.get` on the object refs that are ready.

```
def outer(file):
  outer_is = {}
  unfinished_refs = []
  with open(file, "r"):
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
      outeri, txt = line.split(":")
      ref = ClassX.inner.remote(txt, file, int(outeri))
      outer_is[ref] = int(outeri)
      unfinished_refs.append(ref)

  # This part will get and process tasks as they finish
  while len(unfinished_refs) > 0:
    finished, unfinished_refs = ray.wait(unfinished_refs)
    outeri = outer_is[finished[0]]
    result = ray.get(finished[0])
    ### Process the result here ###
```

Comment: thanks, no i dont use actor .. i use @staticmethod

Comment: i call .get() on all obj-ref after the loop because I dont know how to interleave it .. ergo the question

Comment: afaik  Actor run in a single process unless managed, staticmethod uses all the cores just calling it ... like a function

Comment: at some point  i want to skip collecting obj-refs .. just processing them async.. the loop will go over million of rows. Need something like multiprocessing.imap_unordered()

Comment: Edited my answer, check out the new one

Comment: thanks.. if i dont care about the order is there a way to process them as they arrive but inside the for-loop i.e w/o collecting them.. thats what imap_unordered() does... the file could be a ~1mln lines, collecting 1mln values is not good idea ...  i'm thinking some sort of batch/chunk inner loop  ... thanks anyway

Comment: My answer should parse them i nthe order they finish. To return them to the original list order, you could create a mapping from object ref to original index.